# Laravel 5.2 PHPUnit attach() doesn't move file

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have this method to store new user

```
public function register(CreateUserRequest $request){

    $file = $request->file('idcard');
    $fileName = rand(0, 99999).$file->getClientOriginalName();
    if($request->hasFile('idcard') && $request->file('idcard')->isValid()){
      $request->file('idcard')->move("images/idcard/", $fileName);
    }

    User::create([
      'role_id' => 1,
      'email' => $request->email,
      'password' => $request->password,
      'full_name' => $request->full_name,
      'address' => $request->address,
      'phone' => $request->phone,
      'family_name' => $request->family_name,
      'family_address' => $request->family_address,
      'family_phone' => $request->family_phone,
      'idcard' => $fileName,
      'status' => 'unconfirmed',
      'balance' => 0,
    ]);
    Session::flash('success', 'Please check your email to activate your account.');
    return redirect('/register');

}
```

And I have this unit test

```
public function testNewUserRegistration()
    {
        $this->visit('/register')
          ->type('This is full name', 'full_name')
          ->type('JL. Mulyorejo 226 D', 'address')
          ->type('085788884877', 'phone')
          ->type('Rizky Sugiarto', 'family_name')
          ->type('JL. Kandangan', 'family_address')
          ->type('085766669999', 'family_phone')
          ->attach('/var/www/html/autodealer/images/pics/banner_car.jpg', 'idcard')
          ->type('mail@yahoo.co.id', 'email')
          ->type('123456789', 'password')
          ->type('123456789', 'password_confirmation')
          ->press('Submit')
          ->seeInDatabase('users', ['email' => 'mail@yahoo.co.id', 'role_id' => 1, 'balance' => 0, 'status' => 'unconfirmed'])
          ->seePageIs('/register')
          ->see('Please check your email to activate your account.');
    }
```

If I test my function via browser, it successfuly input database and move file.

But when I test via PHPUnit it pass the test, successfully input database but the image doesn't move.

Is there something wrong with my attach() or something else wrong?

Thanks, any help appreciated.

Comment: The file shouldn't move. `attach` will copy it as a temporary file, just like an upload does (when you upload from your desktop to a website, it doesn't disappear from your desktop, right?) and I suspect after the test runs it removes the file from the final destination as a cleanup step.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for explanation, so attach just simulate the upload process.

Comment: Well, it's more that Laravel's `move` function is moving the temporary file that got uploaded to your server. It wouldn't make sense to move the file your tests use, or the test would fail the second time when it can't find the file. Tests also can clean up after themselves, which I believe is what Laravel is doing here.